# LaTeX 3 for newbies: simple environments do not work

Tags: beamer, latex3

I needed to create a custom environment with more than one optional argument, so I tried with LaTeX 3 (my first experience). However, I can't seem to create not even the simplest environment. Here is an example.

In LaTeX I can do:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\newenvironment{myframe}{\begin{frame}}{\end{frame}}

\begin{document}
\begin{myframe}
test
\end{myframe}
\end{document}
```

which of course does nothing more than a standard frame but works.

In LaTeX 3

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{xparse}
\DeclareDocumentEnvironment{myframe}{}{\begin{frame}}{\end{frame}}


\begin{document}
\begin{myframe}
test
\end{myframe}
\end{document}
```

triggers an error and does not compile.

What am I missing?

Comment: [`beamer`](http://ctan.org/pkg/beamer)'s `frame`s are.... tricky.

Comment: @Werner so Beamer does not work with LaTeX 3? Should I try another approach to solve my original problem?

Comment: Probably not, but using `beamer` as an example might not be optimal. Changing to `article` and using the `center` environment rather than `frame` has no problem. It's just that `beamer`'s `frame`s reads its content almost verbatim; hence the possibility to supply a `fragile` optional argument - it's finicky.

Comment: Unfortunately my original problem is about a custom beamer frame, that's why I used the simplest custom frame I could imagine.

Comment: this is going to be tricky- you're going to need something that is, among other things, `overlay aware`, and accepts all kinds of things in its optional arguments. Are you *sure* that want to start on something so intricate?

Comment: nevermind guys, I wasn't aware beamer frames were a special case. I thought this would offer a good chance to learn some LaTeX 3 basics, but it turns out I was wrong. Thanks all for the feedback.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The short answer is 'this can't work, sorry', at least without some significant changes in `beamer`.

The reason for this is the way `beamer` expects to collect frames, in particular where `\begin{frame}`/`\end{frame}` are 'hidden' inside another environment. With LaTeX2e, the definitions

```
\newenvironment{myframe}{\begin{frame}}{\end{frame}}
```

creates a macro `\endmyframe` which expands *in one step* to `\end{frame}`. However, in the `xparse` version life is more complex, and `\endframe` does not yield `\end{frame}` (or indeed `\end{<something>}` directly. The `beamer` code requires that `\endmymacro` is converted into `\end{<something>}`, and so you get an error. Indeed, you can get errors with for example

```
\newenvironment{myframe}{\frame}{\endframe}
```

or

```
\newenvironment{myframe}{\begin{frame}}{\endframe\endgroup}
```

both of which might otherwise be expected to work.